# 自由度の高いフローチャートと、テキストの相互変換

Tags: html, excel, markdown, グラフ理論

エクセルにより、以下のようなフローチャートを作成しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

矢印の方向はもちろん、オブジェクトの位置やテキストボックスの枠線のタイプにも意味があります。

このフローチャートはエクセルなのでGUIで作成していますが、テキストベースでエクスポート（表現）する方法はあるでしょうか？

Comment: こんな記事を起点に調べていくと何か出来るかもしれません。[【今日使えるどうでもいい雑学】エクセル(xlsx)を解凍、圧縮してみる(XML)](https://qiita.com/mimimi-no-sesese/items/47529e2261c161cad68e), [Excelをunzipして図形の情報を確認する](https://life-is-command.com/excel-unzip/), [Combine unzipped xml files back into a working XLSX file](https://superuser.com/questions/639413/combine-unzipped-xml-files-back-into-a-working-xlsx-file), [DrawingML Shapes](http://www.officeopenxml.com/drwShape.php)

Comment: Excel からのエクスポートが条件ですか？それとも単に例として示しただけで、テキストから記述できるのであればツールは問わないのでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
Excelのエクスポートに拘りなく単に例を示しただけです。テキストベースで上記のようなフローチャート（図形）を再現できれば良いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/)や[flowchart.js](https://flowchart.js.org/)とかが有名でしょうか。他に[Graphviz Alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/graphviz/)や[Flowchart.js Alternatives](https://www.saashub.com/flowchart-js-alternatives)で見つかるものから探してみるとか。

Comment: @YukiIno もう一点、タイトルの「相互変換」は「フローチャートからテキストへの変換」も求めているとも読み取れてしまいます。この辺りも踏まえてタイトルや本文を見直してもらうと、より適切な回答が得られやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

単純に、テキストからフローチャートのような図を作成したいということであれば、DOT 言語を使った [Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/) 辺りが有名だと思います。

具体的にどのような図が作成できるかは、上記サイトの [ギャラリー](https://graphviz.org/gallery/) でも参照できます。

Answer (score 1):

[Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/)を使った[DOT言語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E)の例です。

```toml
digraph G {
    fontname="sans-serif";
    splines="curved";
    penwidth="0.1";
    edge [comment="Wildcard edge", 
          fontname="sans-serif", 
          fontsize=10, 
          colorscheme="blues3", 
          color=2, 
          fontcolor=3];
    node [fontname="serif", 
          fontsize=13, 
          colorscheme="blues4", 
          color="2", 
          fontcolor="4"];
    "n1" [shape="polygon", 
          pos="0,0!", 
          style="dotted", 
          label=<<U>テキストA</U>>];
    "n2" [shape="polygon", 
          pos="2,-1!", 
          label="テキストB"];
    "n1" -> "n2"  [headport="w"];
    "n3" [shape="none", 
          pos="0,-1.5!", 
          image="hatsuhinode.png", 
          penwidth="0.0",
          label=""];
    "n1" -> "n3";
}
```

テキストを`sample.dot`として保存し、下記のコマンドで画像を生成できます。

```
dot -Kfdp -n -Tpng -o sample.png sample.dot
```

[image: 生成した画像]

参考資料:

- [Graphvizとdot言語でグラフを描く方法のまとめ](https://qiita.com/rubytomato@github/items/51779135bc4b77c8c20d)
- [How to force node position (x and y) in graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344221/8248751)
- [Graphviz Documenttion](https://graphviz.org/documentation/)

なおテキストの編集に[Doteditor](https://vincenthee.github.io/DotEditor/)を使用しました。